# Empty, uneditable pg_hba.conf file

Tags: postgresql, authentication, sinatra

I am trying to connect my Sinatra app to PostgreSQL database with this tutorial: http://samuelstern.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/making-a-simple-database-driven-website-with-sinatra-and-heroku/. Everything goes fine until I  try to execute:

```
rake:db migrate
```

then I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

It seems like I should change my permissions in pg_hba.conf file, but, opening it, I see nothing. And, if I try to write something into it, it says it's "*readonly*".

Am I on the right way of getting rid of the error and where to go next?

**edit:** actually, if I try to open it from another text editor, it says I have no permission to.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So **pg_hba.conf** was empty because I was trying to open it with SublimeText and sublime didn't tell me that I was not permitted to read it, it just showed me an empty file.
And to edit **pg_hba.conf** I needed to open it through terminal

```
/etc/postgresql/9.3/main$ sudo subl pg_hba.conf
```

with sudo.

Comment: My sublime2 also wasn't able to open pg_hba.conf even with sudo. Vim worked out.

Comment: Can confirm this is also an issue (and thus fix) when using vim

Comment: Thank you so much @lakesare for asking and answering this question. It was of great help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was not even able to edit or see the content of pg_hba.conf file.

What worked was:

`/etc/postgresql/14/main$ sudo vi pg_hba.conf`

Vi editor with sudo permission on Ubuntu.