# PostgreSQL: FATAL - password authentication failed for user (PG::ConnectionBad)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sinatra

This is my **database.yml**:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myUsername
  username: myUsername
  password: myPassword
  host: localhost
```

So, when I go to my local page, no errors are shown. If I change password in **database.yml** to something incorrect, I get

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myUsername" FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myUsername"
```

error. Therefore, my password is right.

But still, when I run

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get errors no matter if my password is right or wrong. If it's right, I get the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

If it's wrong, I get the same error as on my local page:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myUsername" FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myUsername"
```

What causes it to think that correct password is "not supplied"? Please, any help or information is appreciated, I've been messing with it for two days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. edit pg_hba.conf via *gedit* as *root user* by changing **md5** for **trust**, see here [empty, uneditable pg_hba.conf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974839/empty-uneditable-pg-hba-conf-file) for some issues that may arise
2. **sudo service postgresql restart**
3. restart your local server

Provided your password matches username, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to allow connections to PostgreSQL:

1. **Set a password for the postgres user**
2. **Change the password for the postgres user**

**1. Setting a password for the postgres user**

On Linux systems, there is no default password set.

To set the default password:

Run the psql command from the postgres user account:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

Set the password:

```
\password postgres
```

Enter a password.

Close psql.

```
\q
```

After this, we will change the password for the postgres user in step 2

**N/B:** Step 2 is very important, else you will still have the same **Authenticate Failure** issue.

**2. Change the password for the postgres user**

If you do not know the password for the User

Run the psql command from the postgres user account:

```
sudo passwd postgres
```

Enter a password.

**To test and confirm** the password change or setup, Run the psql command from the postgres user account:

```
su - postgres
```

Enter the new password that you just setup.

To exit the postgreql environment, simply type the command below

```
exit
```

That's all.

If after these steps, you experience an issue like the one below

> Postgresql: FATAL: role does not exist

simply follow the answer here in this link ([Answer: Postgresql: FATAL: role does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189261/10907864)) to fix the issue.

**I hope this helps**